# How to theoretically search for Trigrams in a database

Tags: database, trigram

I have a (theoretical) database and I am storing Trigrams of certain words:

Example:

```
[Javascript] = [jav, ava, vas, asc, scr, cri, rip, ipt]
```

etc... along with many other words in the text field...

If I want to search for **script**, I search for ALL:

```
 [scr, cri, rip, ipt]
```

But what would I search for if I want **" *script "** or **" script* "** (anything before or after **script**)?

Example: **" *script "**

I should get these words: [postscript, javascript, vscript, pscript]... etc

or **" script * "**

I should get these words: [scriptor, scripting, scriptly]... etc

This is not any particular database, SQL or other; I am just trying to understand the theory behind using Trigrams, and what can be done with them.

Comment: When searching for "script", the example shows needing ALL Four trigrams.  Does there also need to be a condition of ONLY those Four trigrams, else many other words would be returned?  The example of " script * " seems to have an unwanted space between "t" and "*", that seems should be removed so that those words would be returned.

Comment: There does not have to be a space there, this is theoretical.  I am just wandering what  I can do to search the trigrams to find words that end in that term or begin with that term.  I was just trying to make a point of my goal (allow those two basic regular types expressions).  I am not sure how MSSQL, for example, does it on the backend.

Comment: If you do not have a coding problem for us to solve, I don't see any problem or question that we can address.

Comment: Hi @donPablo.  There is a coding problem.  I am wondering to search for Trigrams with words ending in "script" and beginning in "script"